# Fractional part of the floor function Integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, euler-mascheroni-constant, fractional-part

Let $\lfloor\rfloor\ $ and $\{\}$ denote the floor function and the fractional part funtion, respectively. Then calculate in closed-form the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{1}\bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\bigg\rfloor\bigg\}dx$$

Comment: Anything you want to add to the question?

Comment: @klirk : What would OP add? Curly braces refer to fractional part of enclosed value, if that's what you mean. Fairly standard.

Comment: He could add why he is interested in the solution, what he tried so far etc...

Comment: @klirk : Okay, fair enough. +1.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Can you compute the value of
$$I_n\equiv\int\limits_{1/n}^{1/(n+1)}\left\{\frac1x \left\lfloor \frac 1x\right\rfloor\right\}\; dx$$
and consider $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$$?

Comment: I hate constructive hints. 
+1

Comment: It can be shown that $I_n = - n \log{\left (n \right )} + n \log{\left (n + 1 \right )} - \frac{1}{n + 1} + \sum_{k=0}^{n - 2} \frac{n}{k + n - \left(n + 1\right)^{2} + 2} $. Doing the final summation seems painful.

Comment: $\sum _{k=0}^{n-2} \frac{n}{k+n-(n+1)^2+2}=n H_{n^2}-n H_{-1+n+n^2}$ where $H_{n}$ is harmonic number.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\bigg\rfloor\bigg\}dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{k+1}}^{\frac{1}{k}}\bigg\{\frac{1}{x}\bigg\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\bigg\rfloor\bigg\}dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{k+1}}^{\frac{1}{k}}\bigg\{\frac{k}{x}\bigg\}dx$$also$$\int_{\frac{1}{k+1}}^{\frac{1}{k}}\bigg\{\frac{k}{x}\bigg\}dx=\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}\int_{\frac{k}{k^2+l+1}}^{\frac{k}{k^2+l}}\dfrac{k}{x}-k^2-ldx=\sum_{l=0}^{k-1}k\ln\dfrac{k^2+l+1}{k^2+l}-(k^2+l)\dfrac{k}{(k^2+l)(k^2+l+1)}=k\ln(1+\dfrac{1}{k})-kH_{k^2+k}+kH_{k^2}$$so the integral would be$$\Large I=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\ln(1+\dfrac{1}{k})-kH_{k^2+k}+kH_{k^2}\approx0.4350$$here is a figure that how the integral converges:

[image]