# An integral involving fractional part and floor function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let  $\{ \cdot \}$ denote the fractional part and $\left \lfloor \cdot \right \rfloor$ the floor function. Evaluate the integral

$$\mathcal{J} = \int_{0}^{1} \left \{ \frac{1}{x} \left \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \right \rfloor \right \}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

***Attempt:*** The change of variables $y=1/x$ is obvious. Applying, the integral transforms to

$$\int_{0}^{1} \left \{ \frac{1}{x} \left \lfloor \frac{1}{x} \right \rfloor  \right \} \, \mathrm{d}x  \overset{y = 1/x}{=\! =\! =\! =\! =\!} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\left \{ y \left [ y \right ] \right \}}{y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y$$

I am unable to convert the last integral into a series and evaluate. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Fractional part of the floor function Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857737/fractional-part-of-the-floor-function-integral) seems useful.

Comment: $$\mathcal{J}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{n^2+j}\right)$$But I cannot go further